# Diagonal calculation of manhattan tourist problem

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need to calculate the Max distance of a Mahattan Tourist Problem with down, right and diagonal matrices.

The calculation for only down and right returns the correct value.
When trying to calculate the max distance including the diagonal paths with a 3x3 matrix it returns the wrong value.

I think the problem is in the line where I calculate the max distance with Math.Max().

For the matrices I used the following test matrices(the input file looks like this):

```
G_down 2 3
  0.1   0.5   0.3
  0.9   0.4   0.7  
---
G_right 3 2
  0.3   0.2
  0.4   0.6
  0.8   0.9
---
G_diag 2 2
  5.6   9.4
  3.2   4.8
---
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//bsp 20.68
namespace MHTP
{
    class Program
    {
        public static double ManhattanProblem(double[,] RightMatrix, double[,] DownMatrix, double[,] DiagonalMatrix)
        {
            int n = RightMatrix.GetLength(0);
            int m = DownMatrix.GetLength(1);
            int d = DiagonalMatrix.GetLength(1);
            double[,] ManhattanMatrix = new double[n, m];

            ManhattanMatrix[0, 0] = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                ManhattanMatrix[i, 0] = ManhattanMatrix[i - 1, 0] + DownMatrix[i - 1, 0];
            }

            for (int j = 1; j < m; j++)
            {
                ManhattanMatrix[0, j] = ManhattanMatrix[0, j - 1] + RightMatrix[0, j - 1];
            }

            /*for (int k = 1; k < d; k++)
            {
                ManhattanMatrix[k, 0] = ManhattanMatrix[k - 1, 0] + DiagonalMatrix[k - 1, 0];
            }*/

            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < m; j++)
                {
                        ManhattanMatrix[i, j] =
                        Math.Max(ManhattanMatrix[i - 1, j] + DownMatrix[i - 1, j],
                        Math.Max(ManhattanMatrix[i, j - 1] + RightMatrix[i, j - 1],
                        ManhattanMatrix[i, j] + DiagonalMatrix[i-1, j-1]));
                }
            }

            return ManhattanMatrix.Cast<double>().Max();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String line;
            int flag = 0;

            //cleanup
            try
            {
                File.Delete(@"right.txt");
                File.Delete(@"down.txt");
                File.Delete(@"diagonal.txt");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Exception Handling
            }


            while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains("---"))
                {
                    flag++;
                }
                if (flag == 0)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter w2 = File.AppendText("down.txt"))
                    {
                        if (line.Contains("-") || line.Contains("G_"))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", " ");
                            w2.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
                    if (flag == 1)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter w1 = File.AppendText("right.txt"))
                    {
                        if (line.Contains("-") || line.Contains("G_"))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", " ");
                            w1.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (flag == 2)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter w3 = File.AppendText("diagonal.txt"))
                    {
                        if (line.Contains("-") || line.Contains("G_"))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", " ");
                            w3.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    }
                }      
            }

            // right
            var linesRight = File.ReadAllLines(@"right.txt")
               .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
               .Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                            .Select(double.Parse)
                            .ToList())
               .ToList();

            var hRight = linesRight.Count();
            var wRight = linesRight.Max(x => x.Count);
            var multiArrayRight = new double[hRight, wRight];

            for (var i = 0; i < linesRight.Count; i++)
                for (var j = 0; j < linesRight[i].Count; j++)
                    multiArrayRight[i, j] = linesRight[i][j];

            // down
            var linesDown = File.ReadAllLines(@"down.txt")
               .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
               .Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                            .Select(double.Parse)
                            .ToList())
               .ToList();

            var hDown = linesDown.Count();
            var wDown = linesDown.Max(x => x.Count);
            var multiArrayDown = new double[hDown, wDown];

            for (var i = 0; i < linesDown.Count; i++)
                for (var j = 0; j < linesDown[i].Count; j++)
                    multiArrayDown[i, j] = (linesDown[i][j]);

            // diagonal
            var linesDiagonal = File.ReadAllLines(@"diagonal.txt")
               .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
               .Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                            .Select(double.Parse)
                            .ToList())
               .ToList();

            var hDiagonal = linesDiagonal.Count();
            var wDiagonal = linesDiagonal.Max(x => x.Count);
            var multiArrayDiagonal = new double[hDiagonal, wDiagonal];

            for (var i = 0; i < linesDiagonal.Count; i++)
                for (var j = 0; j < linesDiagonal[i].Count; j++)
                    multiArrayDiagonal[i, j] = linesDiagonal[i][j];

            double resultManhattan = ManhattanProblem(multiArrayRight, multiArrayDown, multiArrayDiagonal);
            Console.WriteLine(resultManhattan);

        }
    }
}
```

The expected result is 10.4 and I get 10.1.

Answer (score 0):

At first sight it looks like the line:

```
ManhattanMatrix[i, j] + DiagonalMatrix[i-1, j-1]));
```

should read:

```
ManhattanMatrix[i-1, j-1] + DiagonalMatrix[i-1, j-1]));
```